# No results using $this->db->query on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, class

i have  a serious problem:

I am developing a PHP Application using CodeIgniter, and if i use the database query ($this->db->query) the codeigniter results 0, but, if i change for mysql_query, codeigniter return 10 lines...

My Controller **clients.php:**

```
class Clients extends CI_Controller{

protected $viewData;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();        
    $this->load->model('clientsM','',TRUE);
    $this->clientsM->getTen();
}
```

My Model **clientsM:**

```
class Clientes extends CI_Model{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
function getTen(){
    //Using CodeIgniter database class: Dont works....
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10 ");

    //Using mysql_query: Works Fine
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10 ");
}
```

Comment: What does happen when you mena dont work? is $this->db a database object?

Comment: am i the only one that sees the Model file name as "ClientsM.php" but the class name as "Clientes". To my knowledge the filename and class name for models need to be the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling result:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10 ")->result();
```

Try to test that with var_dump

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `result()` on your queried object ,to have array as output use `result_array()`

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10 ");
$result= $query->result();
echo count($result);
```

or to check how many rows returned from query

```
echo $query->num_rows();
```

[**Generating Query Results**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)